# login validating is not working in mern stack

Tags: authentication, web, frontend, backend, mern

it might be something error in one of this code the auth js file doesnt seems working because i enter any credential i get login i have sample database as id 1 and passwd 1234 in students collection

app.js
[image]

this is server.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

login.jsx

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Login = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ enrollment_no: "", password: "" });
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    setData({ ...data, [input.name]: input.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/signin";
      const { data: res } = await axios.post(url, data);
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data);
      window.location = "/";
    } catch (error) {
      if (
        error.response &&
        error.response.status >= 400 &&
        error.response.status <= 500
      ) {
        setError(error.response.data.message);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={"login_container"}>
      <div className={"login_form_container"}>
        <div className={"left"}>
          <form className={"form_container"} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h1>Login to Your Account</h1>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enrollment No"
              name="enrollment_no"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={data.enrollment_no}
              required
              className={"input"}
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              name="password"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={data.password}
              required
              className={"input"}
            />
            {error && <div className={"error_msg"}>{error}</div>}
            <button type="submit" className={"green_btn"}>
              Sign In
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

auth.js

```js
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
    const { enrollment_no, password } = req.body; // Changed Student_id to enrollment_no
    const errors = [];

    if (!enrollment_no || !password) {
        errors.push({ message: "Enrollment No and password are required" }); // Changed Student ID to Enrollment No
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors });
    }

    User.findOne({ enrollment_no: enrollment_no }) // Changed Student_id to enrollment_no
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{ message: "User not found" }] });
            }

            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
                .then(isMatch => {
                    if (!isMatch) {
                        return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ message: "Incorrect password" }] });
                    }

                    const access_token = createJWT(user.enrollment_no, user._id, 3600); // Changed Student_id to enrollment_no

                    jwt.verify(access_token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ message: "Failed to verify token" }] });
                        }

                        if (decoded) {
                            return res.status(200).json({
                                success: true,
                                token: access_token,
                                user: user
                            });
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ message: err.message }] });
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ message: err.message }] });
        });
}
```

i tried to change index file because when i send sigin req i directly redirect without validate and get index.js:7  No routes matched location "/" warning

in case when i enter any credential i get login without authentication